# VBA macro to copy data from one excel file to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 `Excel` workbooks. Both are in different folders. 
I am copying data from one to another using a `macro`.

I observe a subscript out of range error...

Any insights in to this ?

Here is my code

```
Sub copydata()
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String

' check if the file is open 
ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\file1.xlsx") 
If ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\file1.xlsx")
Else
'Just make it active
 Workbooks("C:\file1.xlsx").Activate
 End If

' check if the file is open 

ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\File2.xlsx")
If ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\file2.xlsx")
Else
'Just make it active
 Workbooks("file2.xlsx").Activate

End If

'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("filedata")
shttocopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(3)

End Sub

Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim nam As String

wbname = filename
On Error Resume Next

ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0: Isworkbookopen = False
Case 70: Isworkbookopen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Does the `wkbDest` Workbook definitely have a `Worksheet` with index = 3?

Comment: Which line causes the subscript out of range error?

Comment: Workbooks("C:\file1.xlsx").Activate and Workbooks("file2.xlsx").Activate. (I am writing and executing this macro in the file1.xlsx)

Comment: Oh -- you might need the full file path there (rather than just the file name)

Comment: Added the full path still get an error at this line :  Workbooks("C:\file1.xlsx").Activate

Comment: I am writing and executing this macro in the file2 and not in file1.xlsx

Comment: Thanks Dan! the code worked perfectly :)

Comment: Whew -- we both learned something there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I think I got it. Instead of `.Activate`, we'll just set the book if it's already open. We'll also reference the book by its file name, NOT path (as I had erroneously suggested in a comment above).

This worked for me:

```
Sub copydata()
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String

' check if the file is open
ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\stack\file1.xlsx")
If ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\stack\file1.xlsx")
Else
'Just make it active
 'Workbooks("C:\stack\file1.xlsx").Activate
 Set wkbSource = Workbooks("file1.xlsx")
 End If

' check if the file is open

ret = Isworkbookopen("C:\stack\File2.xlsx")
If ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\stack\file2.xlsx")
Else
'Just make it active
 'Workbooks("C:\stack\file2.xlsx").Activate
 Set wkbDest = Workbooks("file2.xlsx")

End If

'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("filedata")
shttocopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(3)

End Sub

Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim nam As String

wbname = filename
On Error Resume Next

ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0: Isworkbookopen = False
Case 70: Isworkbookopen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Nice answer. I have taken the liberty to answer another question based on your code. I've given you appropriate credit in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307242.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim Book As Workbook ' probably not needed
Set destinationFile = ThisWorkbook ' probably not needed

sourceFile = ("Add your source file name")
sourceFileLocation = ("add your source file location")

Workbooks.Open (sourceFileLocation + "\" + sourceFile)
    Windows(sourceFile).Activate
    Range("A1:X7215").Select                 'Range Values can be changed depending upon the size of the data (total number of records and columns)
    Selection.Copy
    destinationFile.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Windows(sourceFile).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```